# Get selected value from selectbox in gsp page Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to get the value of a selectbox in gsp page on onChange event. I tried the following code:

```
    <g:select id="resource-type" name="resource-type" from="${resultMap?.keySet()}" onchange="${remoteFunction(action:'updateDiffTable'
, update:'diff-table',params:[currentSelection:this.value,resultMap:resultMap])}">
```

I want to set the currentSelection parameter to the value of this selectbox. The problem is that I got null in current code. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<g:select
    id="resource-type" 
    name="resource-type" 
    from="${resultMap?.keySet()}" 
    onchange="${remoteFunction(controller: 'mycontroller', action: 'action1', params:'\'id=\' + this.value')}" />
```

Comment: it is optional but in this case it refers to the id representing each select item. If you dont mention it it will be tostring of each item in your select. remove it if you dont need it.

Comment: I got NPE: caused by NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'id' on null object

Comment: of course instance is null, that was an example. go ahead remove it in your case should not matter if you dont need id. I will update my response.

Comment: How could I add a second parameter whose value is from a page parameter?

Comment: You can concatenate other parameters with & in the same pattern. like this (not tested) params:'\'id=\' + this.value + \'&pageparam=\' + yourVariable '

Comment: I concatenate a map parameter but I got: SyntaxError: missing ] in index expression

... this.value &'resultMap='[internalSkills:[sourceOnly:[], targetOnly:[], diff:[]]...

Comment: try to scape the single quotes